# iOS and watchOS: Notfiied when user starts walking

Tags: ios, watchos, healthkit, core-motion

Is there any way an iOS or watchOS app can be alerted when a user has started walking, when the app is in the background or terminated?

HealthKitStore does provide enableBackgroundDeliveryForType, which works while in the background and will launch the app if its not running, but for the data types I want, the notification is limited to once per hour.